# How can I set a Shape Key value to be a driver's variable?

Tags: drivers

I want a Shape Key's value to be driven by another shape key. But I don't know how to add a shape key value as a variable into a driver. I've selected single property and tried with Object or Mesh types.

[image]

Do I need to select another one?

Comment: Related http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/42037/15543

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- If you use an object in the *Prop* field, the path to the shape key is like this:

  ```
  data.shape_keys.key_blocks["Key 1"].value
  ```
- If you use a mesh, you don't have to put `data` there, so:

  ```
  shape_keys.key_blocks["Key 1"].value
  ```

  [image]
- And if you use the *Key Prop* field with your key block there, then you can just use:

  ```
  key_blocks["Key 1"].value
  ```

  [image]